# DayJS - Strict parsing dates returning false for every attempt with timezones

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I'm migrating my old code from momentJS for the dayJS.

```
isValidTimestampDateTime: function (date) {

    const datetimeFormats = [
        "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ", // 2023-03-01T15:41:00+01:00
        "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ", // 2023-03-22T11:51:53.766+01:00
        "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]", // 2023-03-22T11:51:53.766Z
    ];

    return dayjs(date, datetimeFormats, true).isValid();
},
```

Why this return always false? In momentJS always worked even with the strict params. Now, only returns true to them if the strict param isn't filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a version issue. I was using 1.1.17. In the 1.1.19, it actually works.

Comment: You should accept your answer, or just delete the question.

Comment: @RobG I would leave it, it might be useful information to somebody else.